# Include JavaScript file in HTML won't work as <script .... />

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to include a javascript file on every page of a site. I can do this with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myFile.js" ></script>
```

This works fine - however as there's nothing between the two tags, I wanted to change it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myFile.js" />
```

If I do this, it doesn't work - nothing after that line loads on the page.

Any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: Is this within the <header> tags?

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Comment: I had similar problem. Reason might be JS file cannot be included in stand-alone tag.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Unfortunately, the HTML specs for  REQUIRE a closing tag...

HTML Standard, [section 18.2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)

> 18.2.1 The SCRIPT element
>
> Start tag: **required**, End tag: **required**

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug, it's standard behavior.

Also, empty HTML elements are often not rendered:

`<div style="background:red"></div>` displays, `<div style="background:red" />` doesn't

Comment: This element IS rendered but not visible, since it's size is zero pixel height and width

Answer (score 2):

`HTML` doesn't support self closing tags. If you want to use them you need to use an xml based doctype AND serve the file as xml.

XHTML or the xml serialisation of html5 would both work.

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>XHTML5 Template</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Save this in a file with a `.xhtml` extension and open it in a modern browser and the self closing tag will work.