# accessing Java variable from Javascript in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSP Variable Accessing in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803906/jsp-variable-accessing-in-javascript)

I have a java variable and a javascript on a jsp page.

```
<% int max=70; %>
```

How do I get the variable from the script?

```
var x = ???
```

I tried document.getElementById() but unfortunately it didn't seem to work as it isn't a html element

this is my error:

Unable to compile class for JSP:

```
An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /search.jsp
max cannot be resolved
10:     function validateForm() {
11:         var x=document.forms["search"]["capacity"].value;
12:         var y=document.forms["search"]["date"].value;
13:         var m=<%=max%>;
14:         if (isNaN(x)) {
15:             alert("Capacity must be an Integer");
16:             return false;
```

Answer (score 6):

JSP is a HTML code producer. JS is part of HTML.

Just let JSP print JS variable accordingly.

```
var x = <%=max%>;
```

Open page in browser, rightclick and *View Source* to verify if JSP-generated HTML/JS syntax is proper.

#### See also:

- [Our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, using *scriptlets* is considered discouraged since a decade. To learn about the right ways, carefully read [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202) Assuming that `max` is available in the EL scope, you could print it as follows:

```
var x = ${max};
```

Comment: this is my error Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /search.jsp
max cannot be resolved
10:  function validateForm() {
11:   var x=document.forms["search"]["capacity"].value;
12:   var y=document.forms["search"]["date"].value;
13:   var m=<%=max%>;
14:   if (isNaN(x)) {
15:    alert("Capacity must be an Integer");
16:    return false;

Comment: That just means that `max` is nowhere been declared in the same scope. Are you sure that you've a `<% int max=70; %>` in the same scope? For example, if it's in a different JSP page or in a method declaration then it obviously won't work (exactly like as in normal Java classes).