# The meaning of $ sign used in my jsp page

Tags: html, jsp

what is the meaning of the $ sign in the following code:

```
<h1 class="title">Welcome ${consumer.first_name} </h1>
```

Comment: It is called EL stands for Expression Language which is different from JSTL. Moreover, `first_name` is a hateful variable name that doesn't confirm the Java naming convention. It should be `firstName` (always - as long as you're using the Java language).

Answer (score 3):

It is an expression (think of it as a means to access the value of a Java object).

```
${consumer.first_name}
```

is equivalent to

```
<%
    out.print(consumer.getFirst_Name());
%>
```

Here, `consumer` would be an attribute in one of the scopes (request, session etc)

Read up on [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html)

Answer (score 0):

**That is one of the way to access variables**. Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803906/jsp-variable-accessing-in-javascript).