# Accessing java variable from javascript on same jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Is it possible to access a String type variable defined in jsp from a javascript on the same page?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">  
foo();
function foo()  
{  
var value = "<%=myVar%>";  
alert(value);   
}  
</script>  
</head>
<body>

<%

String myVar="blabla";
%>

</body>

</html>
```

In eclipse I am getting an error

```
myVar cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: Where is your myVar defined?

Comment: `<%` and `<%=` blocks are evaluated in the order in which they're found on the page. You need to put the one that declares `myVar` before the one that uses it.

Comment: Although, ideally, you wouldn't use scriptlets at all.

Comment: Why not to use scriptlets?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSP Variable Accessing in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803906/jsp-variable-accessing-in-javascript)

Comment: @RafiKamal it's not a duplicate. Current OP's question is why its current approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This won't work since you're trying to use an undefined variable. The code is generated like this:

```
... = myVar;
//...
String myVar = "blabla";
```

Doesn't make sense, right? So, in order to make this work you should declare the variable before using it (as always):

```html
<%
    String myVar="blabla";
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    foo();
    function foo() {
        var value = "<%=myVar%>";
        alert(value);
    }
</script>
```

Still, usage of scriptlets is **extremely discouraged**. Assuming you're using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) and [Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) (EL), this can be rewritten to:

```html
<c:set name="myVar" value="blabla" />
<script type="text/javascript">  
    foo();
    function foo() {
        var value = "${myVar}";
        alert(value);
    }
</script>
```

If your variable has characters like `"` inside, then this approach will faile. You can escape the result by using `<c:out>` from JSTL:

```
var value = "<c:out value='${myVar}' />";
```

More info:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197)

Comment: @VgeShi I know, that was a recommendation.

Comment: what if myVar contains " characters? Isn't there a safe way to use it without escaping such characters manually??

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i want the opposite of that . i want to get javascript value and pass it to java variable

Comment: @ShaabanEbrahim for that purpose, send a request to the server from your client side (javascript).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i want to encrypt password by method in java without need to send request to server

Comment: @ShaabanEbrahim Javascript is in client side, Java is in server side. There's no way to communicate to a Java process from Javascript, unless you're running Javascript on the server side as well, but I doubt that's what you're doing.