# How to parse json java object in javascript

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp

Here is my code :

Display.jsp:

```
<%
response.setContentType("application/json");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
Employee employee = new Employee("RAM","ram@gmail.com");
json.put("employee",employee);
out.println(json);
%>
```

how can i parse employee name and email using js,

i want to set those values into a table

Any ideas...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading a JSP variable from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803906/reading-a-jsp-variable-from-javascript)

Comment: here i'm not going to render my jsp variable to the view directly..i just give my jsp json variable to javascript...please take a clear look...

Comment: The accepted answer in that post is not just about rendering jsp variables to view. Have you tried something like `var jsvariable="<%= json %>";`?

Comment: Are you using ajax call?

Comment: i'm not using any ajax call at this time....to communicate with jsp and js in between some xml/json required thats why i prefer json

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse thorough the object in the javascript to print its `key` and `value` ,

```
function inside_obj(o) {
    var Otype = typeof o 
    if (Otype == "object") {
        for (var key in o) {
            print("key: ", key)
            inside_obj(o[key])
        }
    } else {
        print(o)
    }
}
```

[Learn More. .](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Js runs on the client-side, whereas JSP - on the server side. Therefore, if you want to parse your JSP output HTML on the client side, you'll need to select this output (using jQuery is the most convenient way. Make sure you output it in a HTML tag with an ID you can use in jQuery selector). Then, use JSON.parse() to parse the json.

Also, why do you need JS to process your JSON? Can't you do that on the server side? Unless you're using AJAX, I can hardly think of a reason not to completely process your model on the server side.