# How to pass String Variable in Javascript Function?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Here is my code :

JSP :

```
String userId = rs.getString("user_id");

<center><a href="#"  onclick="edit(\'' + userId + '\');">Edit</a></center>
```

JavaScript :

```
 function edit(id)
 {
         alert(" user id is "+id);

 }
```

but it does not works.

it gives error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading a JSP variable from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803906/reading-a-jsp-variable-from-javascript)

Comment: Is this you've tried to code?? Nobody will understand what is the actual problem. Please post a code that everyone here can understand what is bugging over here

Comment: Try this: <center><a href="#"  onclick="edit(edit(<%=userId %>));">Edit</a></center>

Answer (score -2, accepted):

hey frinds use this code

```
<center><a href="#"  onclick="edit(  <%=userId %>  ;">Edit</a></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this

```
var userId = '${userId}'   <-- with ${} you get the var.
```

or:

```
... onclick="edit('userId')" ...


function edit(userId) {
    var id = rs.getString(userId);
    alert('id is: ' + id);
}
```

Best regards.