# autoComplete tag appears on the wrong place

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces and JSF to do my school work and used jQueryUI Theme roller to style it, and the specific tag: `<p:autoComplete>` has a bug when the CSS is active (when I disable css it works fine), this is how it looks:bug

[image]

the autoComplete should be right beside "Modelo:", but it's on the page corner.

I've found this code with "autocomplete":

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    cursor: default;
}
```

This same code also appears in `jquery-ui.css` and `jquery-ui.structure.css`. There are also some JavaScript codes with "autocomplete", but they were to big to put in here so I placed them on this link:
http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/4282

I don't understand much of CSS and Javascript, so I'm asking you guys to help me with this bug.

FYI: I'm using the <`p:autocomplete>` inside a `<p:panelGrid>`, also, sorry for the English mistakes :)

Comment: Use jQuery UI Autocomplete. Refer my asnwer !

Comment: Thank you @Venkatraman, but it was far more simple to solve this, I've just changed .ui-autocomplete position in css, from absolute to relative, of course, I've to change in every file that .ui-autocomplete appeared.

Comment: Nice. Add it as your answer in the same question :) !

Comment: Next time, please create a question with a little less broad tags. You might get non-pf related answers

Comment: Instead of changing library files you could just create your own css class which overrides position attribute and add it where you need it. Changing it globally can cause problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

it was far more simple to solve this, I've just changed .ui-autocomplete position in css, from absolute to relative, of course, I've to change in every file that .ui-autocomplete appeared

Comment: This answer is way more applicable than the other one

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery` and `jQuery UI` Refer the below Snippet.

Reference URL: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```js
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: I've got run a method who returns an arrayList in a java class to pull the autoComplete tags, is there a way to put this arrayList in that javascript function?

Comment: Yep create this a Rest GET API call

Comment: if its hard coded variable from java then refer url on how to add: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803906/reading-a-jsp-variable-from-javascript

Comment: Wrong answer for a (badly tagged) PrimeFaces question

Comment: @Kukeltje, initially this was expected. so suggested angular way autocomplete !

Comment: Angular way? jQuery way you mean