# Get Spring @RequestParam in ajax request

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I'm trying to get a Java object in my javascript. I'm using a ajax request to get this object.
Here is my code :

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/sendSMS", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void sendSMS(HttpServletRequest request, 
                    HttpServletResponse response, 
                    final ModelMap contactModel,
                    @RequestParam(value = "id") final String contactId) { ... }
```

and my ajax request :

```
var $this = $(this);
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/contacts/sendSMS?id=${param.id}',
    data : $this.serialize(),
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(json) {
        alert("success");
        $.each(json,function(index,element) {
            if (index == "message") {
                message = element;
                alert(message);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The error I got in Eclipse is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${param.id}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.controller.contact.ContactController.sendSMS(ContactController.java:259)
```

This line is :

```
Integer id = Integer.parseInt(contactId);
```

**EDIT :** 
It works when I hard code the id. I just modify `url` like this :

```
var smsUrl = '/contacts/sendSMS?id=113';
url : smsUrl,
```

Now my problem is that I don't know how to get the id value dynamically.

Comment: By the way your original javascript code was missing a closing parenthesis for `success` function. http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35974083/2

Comment: `There is an error in Eclipse after the last "}" here ${param.id}` maybe it's related to that `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
${param.id}
```

This value comes from Spring. JavaScript files should be seperated from JSP files. You can for example connect Spring variable to HTML tag in your JSP file like `<form>`:

```
<form myattribute="${param.id}">
... 
</form>
```

and now you can fetch this value in your JavaScript file with jQuery like this:

```
var myId = $('form').attr('myattribute');

$.ajax({ 
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/contacts/sendSMS?id=' + myId 
    ...
});
```

You can also use the data-* attribute to embed custom data in your HTML tags like:

```
 <form data-myvariable="${param.id}">
 ... 
 </form>
```

and then in JS file:

```
var myId = $('form').data("myvariable");

$.ajax({ 
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/contacts/sendSMS?id=' + myId 
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `url : '/contacts/sendSMS?id=${param.id}'` to `url : '/contacts/sendSMS?id=' + ${param.id}`

Comment: There is an error in Eclipse after the last "}" here ${param.id}

Comment: "Syntax error on token "{", . expected" for the first {
and
"Syntax error on token ",", { expected after this token" after the second }

Comment: What is param.id in your JS?

Comment: Instead of `${param.id}` use JS variable which has the id value `'/contacts/sendSMS?id=' + id` or if just testing use some hard coded value then your url should be `'/contacts/sendSMS?id=12'`

Comment: I try with hard coded value, it works. But I don't know how I can get the id value dynamically. I thought it was ${param.id}

Comment: Do you know how can I do to have the id value in my JS ?

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX call you are defining the url as a static value, while the id should be dynamic. Change it to:

```
 url : '/contacts/sendSMS?id='+${param.id},
```

Comment: There is an error in Eclipse after the last "}" here ${param.id}

Answer (score 0):

```
url : '/contacts/sendSMS?id='+${param.id}
```

should to the magic, but as you mentioned in earlier answers to you maybe mix JavaScript and JSPs ?

You might want also to take a look at: [Reading a JSP variable from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803906/reading-a-jsp-variable-from-javascript)

Comment: This doesn't work, I don't know what is ${param.id}. Do you know how can I do to have the id value in my JS ?

Comment: What should ${param.id} contain? Where should it come from?