# Dynamically adding drop down list to a jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have inserted my code here.What i am trying to do is when the user selects an option in Phase menu then the activity menu should be dynamically produced.This code is running fine but when I select an option from phase menu it shows error at onchange function G() is not defined.

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import ="org.indresh.javanet.Employee"
    import="org.indresh.javanet.Database" import="org.indresh.javanet.MySqlConnector"
    import="java.util.HashMap" import="java.util.ArrayList" import="java.util.HashSet"
    import="java.util.Arrays" import="java.util.Iterator" import="java.util.Set"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var create=0;
  function G(){
   if (create == 1) {
                removeDrop();
            }
   
   var a=document.getElementById('phase1');
   
   var wheretoput=document.getElementById('acc');
   var createselect=document.createElement('select');
   createselect.setAttribute('name',"Activity");
   wheretoput.appendChild(createselect);
   ArrayList<String> act=new ArrayList<String>();
   act=actpha.get(a);
   
   for(var i=0;i<act.length;i++){
    var createoption=document.createElement('option');
    createoption.text=act.get(i);
    createoption.value=act.get(i);
    createselect.add(createoption,createselect.options[null]);
    }
    create = 1; 
  }
  function removeDrop() {
            var d = document.getElementById('acc');

            var oldmenu = document.getElementByName('Activity');

            d.removeChild(oldmenu);
        }
  function timesheetrecorded(){
   alert("Your TimeSheet has been recorded");
  }
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Employee TimeLine</title>
<meta name="description" content="Description of your site goes here">
  <meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  
</head>
<body>
<%Employee e=(Employee)session.getAttribute("Employee"); 
  String[][] phaseactivity;
  Boolean temp=(Boolean)session.getAttribute("Manager");
  int i;
  ArrayList<String> pid=new ArrayList<String>();
  Database db=new Database();
  MySqlConnector scon=new MySqlConnector();
  HashMap<String,String> pr=new HashMap<String,String>();
  pr=db.getProjects(scon);
  pid=db.getAllProjectID(scon);
  HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> actpha=new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
  actpha=db.getphaseactivity(scon);
  Set<String> phases=new HashSet<String>();
  phases=actpha.keySet();
  ArrayList<String> ph=new ArrayList<String>();
  Iterator it=phases.iterator();
  while(it.hasNext()){
   ph.add((String)it.next());
  }
  %> 
<div class="main-out">
<div class="main">
<div class="page">
<div class="top">
<div class="header">
<div class="header-top">
<h1><span>Drivedge</span></h1>
<p>Call Us: +91 (0)20 65231515.</p>
<div class="namename">
<p>Hello <%=e.getEmployeeName() %></p></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="topmenu">
<ul>
  <li><%if(temp){%><a href="AddEmployeeToProject.jsp"><button type="button">Add Employees to your Project</button></a><%} %>
  <a href="logout.jsp"><button type="button">LogOut</button></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="header-img">

</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
<div class="content-left">
<div class="row1">


</div>
<div class="row2">

<form name="form1" action="timesheet" method="get" onSubmit="timesheetrecorded()">
  <div Class="project">
  Select Project:<select name="Project">
  <option value="">--</option>
   <%for(i=0;i<pr.size();i++){%>
   <option value="<%=pid.get(i)%>"><%=pr.get(pid.get(i)) %></option><%} %>
  </select></div>
  <div class="phase">
  Select Phase:<select name="Phase" id="phase1" onchange="G()">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <%for(String p:ph){%>
   <option value="<%=p%>"><%=p %></option><%} %>
  </select></div>
  <div class="activity" id="acc">
  Activity:</div>
  <div class="date">Date:<input type="date" name="date" format="yyyymmdd"/></div>
  <div class="time">
  Time Devoted(Hrs):<input type="text" name="time"/></div>
  <div class="submit2">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="timesheetrecorded()"/></div>
  
 </form>

</div>
</div>
<div class="content-right">

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">

</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're mixing Java into your Javascript. That won't work.

Comment: ok. So what should I do to create a dynamic drop down menu in jsp file?

Comment: just advice put your JS code before </body>  sometimes  If Js code in the header, then the elements they are attempting to access might not exist yet.
why you are using JS code what 's your goal ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this link may help you

[Reading a JSP variable from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803906/reading-a-jsp-variable-from-javascript)

**Answer copied from that question**

```
<html> 
<head>
<script language="javascript"> 

function access(){ 
  <% String str="Hello World"; %>
   var s="<%=str%>"; 
   alert(s); 
} 

</script> 
</head> 

<body onload="access()"> 
</body> 

</html>
```

Get your ArrayList into any jSP variable

```
<%=ArrayList<String> act=new ArrayList<String>();
            act=actpha.get(a); %>
```

After that use that variable into JS

```
 var jsact="<%=act%>";
```

from there your code work fine.
This code may not perfect but it may help you.