# how to display model object in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

Here is my RestController Class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/user")
public class Test {

    @RequestMapping(value="/{userEmailId}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getUser(@PathVariable("userEmailId") String userEmailId){

        //something goes here and get User class object

        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("showuser");
        mav.addObject("user", user);//user is User class object
        return mav;
    }
}
```

I want to display this user object in showuser.jsp using Angular JS How can I do that?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803906/reading-a-jsp-variable-from-javascript

Comment: Thanks for replay, I don't want to use EL(Expressional Language) and scriplets

Comment: _"I want to display this user object in showuser.jsp"_ And you have decline every offered solution so far. So what exactly is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Below is sample example assuming your user object have firstname and lastname:

```
 <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="userController"> 
    <form action="demo_form.html">
      First name: <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="fname"><br>
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" ng-model="lname"><br>

    </form>
    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('userController', function($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "/user/xyz@a.com"
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.fname = response.fname;
             $scope.lname = response.lname;
        }, function myError(response) {
            //handling error
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I don't want to make request here, I have another page to request.I just want to display the user data. I wan to use it as view