# Create a JSP element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp

I need to create a jsp form with javascript. The problem is to assign the data path.

Imagine $form.work = "Hello Work";

If I create the form with html:

`<div id='workForm'>
    Work:<input value=${form.work}></input>
</div>`

The input will show the work value (Hello Work). But I need to create this div form with js, something like:

```
var oDiv = document.createElement('div');
oDiv.setAttributte('id', 'workForm');
var oInput= document.createElement('input');
oDiv.appendChild(oInput)
...
```

I tryed to add an attribute to the input like:

```
oInput.addAttributte('value', '${form.work}')
```

But it shows: ${form.work} not Hello Work

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this
[Reading a JSP variable from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803906/reading-a-jsp-variable-from-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var work = "<%=form.work%>";
```

or

```
var work = "${form.work}"
alert(work);
```

If the window/ System alert had provided what you need, then you can setAttribute("value", work) to the hidden field or the JSP element you needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, you must use `template literals` (backticks) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
oInput.setAttribute('value', `${form.work}`)
```

Comment: I tryed but i got a undefined message